# IOS absolute position 'unset' not working

Tags: ios, css, media-queries

In the following....

`div.foobar { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0}`

`@media screen and (max-width:400px) { div.foobar { top: unset; bottom: 0;} }`

...in most browsers results in the div moving from the top to the bottom of the enclosing div ( `position: relative` ) on smaller screens. In IOS it doesn't. The only workaround seems to be `top: 95%` but that's not predictable enough.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: `top: auto` or place the first rule inside a mediaquery for `min-width: 401px`

Comment: spot on ! thanks, So  `:auto` is the best practice to unset absolute positioning.

Answer (score 3):

CSS doesn't support `unset` for the `top` property.

You must use `auto`, a percentage, or a length. (edit: or `inherit`, or `initial`)

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#box-offsets-trbl for more information on box offsets in CSS.